# State machine program design in FreeRTOS - vTaskStartScheduler in a switch statement

Tags: operating-system, embedded, state-machine, atmel, freertos

I have a program design question in FreeRTOS:

I have a state machine with 4 states, and 6 tasks. In each state, different tasks must be executed, excepting Task1, which is always active:

State 1: Task1, Task2, Task3
State 2: Task1, Task2, Task3, Task4
State 3: Task1, Task5
State 4: Task1, Task6

Task1, Task3, Task4, Task5 and Task6 are periodic, and each one reads a different sensor.
Task2 is aperiodic, it sends a GPRS alarm only if a threshold is reached.

The switching between the states is determined by events from the sensor input of each task.

The initial approach for the design of main() is to have a switch to control the states, and depending on the state, suspend and activate the corresponding tasks:

```
void main ()
{
    /* initialisation of hw and variables*/
    system_init(); 

    /* creates FreeRTOS tasks and suspends all tasks except Task1*/
    task_create();

    /* Start the scheduler so FreeRTOS runs the tasks */
    vTaskStartScheduler(); 

    while(true)
    {
        switch STATE:
            case 1:
                suspend(Task4, Task5, Task6);
                activate(Task2, Task3);
                break;
            case 2:
                suspend(Task5, Task6);
                activate(Task2, Task3, Task4);
                break;
            case 3:
                suspend(Task2, Task3, Task4, Task6); 
                activate(Task5);
                break;
            case 4: 
                suspend(Task2, Task3, Task4, Task5);
                activate(Task6);
                break;
    }
}
```

My question is: where should I call vTaskStartScheduler(), in relation with the switch? It seems to me that in this code, once the vTaskStartScheduler is called, the program will never enter the switch statement.

Should I create another task always active to control the state machine, which has the previous while and switch statements inside, such as the following pseudocode?

```
task_control()
{
    while(true)
    {
        switch STATE:
            case 1: 
                   suspend(Task4, Task5, Task6);  
                   execute(Task2, Task3); 
            and so on...
    }
}
```

Any advice will be much appreciated...

Comment: 'Task1, Task3, Task4, Task5 and Task6 are periodic, and each one reads a different sensor.' why the contraints, then?  Why can they not all run?

Comment: These constrains are due to the specific state requirements of the application. For example, in state 2, only sensors 5 and 6 must be read, others must be off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, `vTaskStartScheduler()` will, as the name suggests, start the scheduler. Any code after it will only execute when the scheduler is stopped, which in most cases is when the program ends, so never. This is why your `switch` won't run.

As you have already eluded to, for your design you could use a 'main' task to control the others. You need to have created this and registered it with the scheduler before calling `vTaskStartScheduler()`.

On a side note, if you do go with this approach, you only want to suspend/resume your tasks on first entry into a state, not on every iteration of the 'main' task.

For example:

```
static bool s_first_state_entry = true;

task_control()
{
    while (true)
    {
        switch (STATE)
        {
        case 1:
            if (s_first_state_entry)
            {  
                // Only do this stuff once              
                s_first_state_entry = false;
                suspend(Task4, Task5, Task6);  
                execute(Task2, Task3); 
            }
            // Do this stuff on every iteration
            // ...
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}  

void set_state(int state)
{
    STATE = state;
    s_first_state_entry = true;
}
```

Comment: _you only want to suspend/resume your tasks on first entry into a state, not on every iteration of the 'main' task._    If I understand your point, in my second code above every time 'main' task is executed, it will check the state, and even if the state dind't change it will suspend and resume it's corresponding tasks in an unnecesary way. Thus, in order to avoid this unnecesary actions, every time the we enter in the switch statement we should check whether the current state is already active, and if it is, don't suspend/resume, isn't it?

Comment: Exactly. Please see the edited answer for an example, and please accept the answer if you're happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

As Ed King metioned, your solution contains a major design flaw. That is - after starting scheduler, no code that's specified after it in the main function will ever execute until the scheduler is stopped.

I suggest implementing your state logic in Idle task (remember to include delays in your tasks not to starve the Idle hook from processing time). Idle task could block and unblock the tasks depending on the current state by menas of semaphores. Remember though, that the Idle hook is a task with a lowest possible priority, so be careful when designing your system. The solution suggested by me may be completely wrong when the tasks consume most of the processing time not allowing the Idle task to switch states.

Alternatively, you can create a superior task as mentioned by Ed King, with the highest priority.

To be honest, everything depends on what the task are really doing.

Comment: Two of the tasks read continuous data from an acelerometer, so I guess that will prevent the Idle Task to change states.                                           
I have a question regarding how to pass the state change info between the event detection tasks and the superior task, so I will start another question, and I would very much appreciate your advice