# State machine program design in FreeRTOS - Task managing the state changes

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, embedded, state-machine, freertos

Following on the discussion at [State machine program design in FreeRTOS - vTaskStartScheduler in a switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46685292/state-machine-program-design-in-freertos-vtaskstartscheduler-in-a-switch-state), I have a state machine with 4 states, each of them with different tasks reading sensor data.

When a sensor data reaches a threshold, its task has to cause a state change.

The idea is to have a superior task which controls the states (and suspends/resumes corresponding tasks) with a switch statement. My question is: how should the sensor tasks communicate the STATE with the superior task?

One proposed solution is to have a set_state function which is called by the event generating task, but I read that having global variables in FreeRTOS is discouraged. I thought to implement it through Queues:

1- Task1 detects sensor threshold, and sends STATE to a Queue.

2- Superior task is blocked waiting to receive data from Queue. When it receives STATE, the switch statement processes the state change.

If this approach is correct, my doubt relates on how and where should be STATE defined (global, or just existing in the stack of each task, or the superior task...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STATE` should exist only where it needs to, 'in' the superior task. I'm presuming you're using C, so declare `STATE` as a `static` variable in "superior_task.c" (or whatever it's called). This means it can then only be affected within that file - the C equivalent to a private member variable in C++.

Then, if your inferior tasks need to affect a state change, they post a state change event to a queue managed by the superior task. When the queue is processed, the superior state makes the change to the private `STATE` variable.

If other tasks need to know what the state is for their own processing, they can use an accessor for the private variable, e.g., `State get_state() { return STATE; }`. As Martin says though, the other tasks shouldn't need to know the state, as otherwise there's inter-dependencies between tasks that shouldn't exist.

Comment: Yes, using just one thread to manage the state-machine, with all others queueing inputs and waiting for action requests to be posted back, is a good design that is relatively easy to debug, however 'If other tasks need to know what the state is for their own processing' - they should not!

Comment: Fair point, I added that more to show how the state can be viewed when it's private.

Comment: Yes, inferior tasks will not need to know the state, as they will be suspended or resumed by the superior task.   Then, if I have just a task_definitions.c which has all the definitions and creation of all FreeRTOS tasks together, I guess that STATE could just be a local variable inside superior task function, isn't it?

Comment: It can be a local variable in the `task()` function, which will put the variable on the task's stack. This is fine, and an implementation choice. Personally, I'd use a `static` variable in file scope, as it means you can then use it in other functions, like a helper for `set_state()` (see my answer to your other question).

Comment: if it's static and the other tasks are also declared in the same .c file, would that mean that they will all see the same variable, and therefore should be protected by a mutex?

Comment: @AlvaroMuro only the state-machine handler task should have access to state.  Siince it's inputs are serialized by the producer-consumer queue from which it derives all events, there should no need for any mutex.  I would put it on the stack of the SM-handler, so preventing any likely direct access from outside.  If other tasks can get at the state, even for read-only, they are effectively breaking the SM - they may take inappropriate actions because they read the state directly before queued events that would change it - UB.  UB in a SM is umm... 'very bad' :)

Comment: Yes, anything in the same file can see that variable - it has file scope. Personally, I wouldn't create all my tasks in the same file, I would split each into its own file to logically separate responsibility and allow some flexibility in implementation. If you have everything in one file, then my approach of using a static variable will still work but you have the potential to introduce some nasty (and hard to debug) behaviour into the state machine if you care-freely start using it in multiple tasks. This is what Martin James is eluding to - don't do this.